# javafx2.0 - force refresh the scene

Tags: javafx-2, fxml

In my app, one scene having the popup dialog which consists of some fields and buttons. If you click on the button then I want to dismiss the popup dialog as well as update the some fields in the scene. Indirectly I want to refresh scene. is it possible?

I used the following code.Here what I did is, I get the controller of that scene and then update the field using id. but it doesn't work.

```
 URL location = AdmincontrolController.class.getResource("admincontrol.fxml");

 FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
 fxmlLoader.setLocation(location);
 fxmlLoader.setBuilderFactory(new JavaFXBuilderFactory());
 try {
     Parent root = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load(location.openStream());
     AdmincontrolController controller = fxmlLoader.getController();
     System.out.println("AdmincontrolController: "+controller);
     controller.setEmail(item.getEmail());
 } catch (IOException ex) {
     Logger.getLogger(Add_loginController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
 }
```

**Scenario:**

***scene***
[image]

***Popup*** - If we clicks on the add then we need to dismiss that dialog and change the email text on the previous scene.
[image]

Comment: Can you post the actionHandler of "Add" where you dismiss that dialog and change the email text?

Answer (score 1):

As Alexander mentioned above, updating the underlying text property of the object you are using to display the email should Just Work.  You need to make sure that you are working with the property (see [Oracle Java FX Property Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm) for more info).  As a concrete example:

**FXML**

```
 <Text fx:id="email" />
 <TextField fx:id="emailInput" />
 <Button onAction="#doSetEmail" text="Set Email"/>
```

In your controller, use the @FXML annotation to inject concrete instances of objects and set the handler to adjust the text:

**Controller**

```
@FXML
Text email;

@FXML
TextField emailInput;

@FXML
public void doSetEmail(ActionEvent ae) {
    email.setText(emailInput.getText());
}
```

Alternatively, you could just bind the email text property to the email label property so that changes would automatically get propagated:

```
email.textProperty().bind(emailInput.textProperty());
```

You could do this in your controller `initialize()` method.

Now, the caveat to all this working depends on how you are handling the event and what you are doing in this. You still haven't posted the code for that as requested by the first answer, so you may be having issues there. Namely, if you are starting threads and then trying to update UI elements on the JavaFX thread from a worker thread, then you can get into trouble (potentially) with things not updating. This depends substantially on the structure of your objects, and you have not given enough information to comment in any meaningful way on that.

- chooks

Answer (score 0):

JavaFX is built so that you don't need to directly call the scene update routine. All you need - update  properties of scene components, and they will be updated on the nearest pulse.

So, all you need is to update properties. Or, is there any real trouble?

Comment: Yes, I changed the properties but it doesn't effect the UI.

Comment: is it required to call methods like setGraphic(root) for updating the UI with our changes?

Comment: Yes, you provide new values for properties (gprahic node for instance) and there is listener on this property, which requires skin class to update layout. When layoutis updated, scenegraph will mark subtree (in scene graph) as dirty and subtree will be rerendered

Answer (score 0):

refreshing scene its not possible without closing...but if you can do class level declaration for control..i.e make them static its may work...

try this..

make a function in main file.

MainPanel.java

```
public static void SetMail(String email)
{
txtmail.setText(email);
}
```

LoginPanel.java

```
 btnclear.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent t) {                      
            MainPanel.SetMail(txtEmail.getText());


    }          
    });
```

Comment: Adding a public static method to solve this is a horrible idea.

Comment: but we can make class level declaration...i used it and its perfectly work.

Comment: The path to wisdom is NP hard.  Someday you may realize why using class level static methods to work with instance data is a bad idea.  Maybe you need this as a hack to get you through a demo, but this is technical debt that is easily (and best) avoided.

Comment: okey @chooks thanks for your suggestion...i would try another things and codes and try to gives you better way.

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you have the Feeling that you manually want to update a Scene you should probably use a backgroundWorker Thread to do the work.
This way your UI Thread can use the time to update Labels etc.